# Installer Dialog comes up with Scroll bars on 800x480 resolution

Tags: windows-installer, dialog, resolution, wise

I am building an msi using WISE. The Dialogs appear fine when run on a 1280x800 resolution screen.
But when I run the same msi on a 800x480 resolution screen, the installer dialog appears really huge and you cannot see the whole dialog on the screen.However, the dialog now comes up with a vertical and horizontal scrollbar allowing you to scroll and view it fully.

Is there any property I need to set to adjust the installer dialog such that it appears properly on both higher and lower resolution screens?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the lowest resolution those forms are designed for was 800x600, as per Windows XP design guidelines. You're missing that target by 120 pixel in height of your screen.

That said, you can probably write an a C++ based solution by building the WISE installer from sources, and manually editing the .rc file. (Yes, I know that's vague)